# No hay resultados usando jQuery autocomplete y MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

El *autocomplete* de este código debe mostrarme los artículos que tengo dentro de una base de datos de `MySql`, pero cada vez que se escribe algo dentro de la caja de texto me muestra `no search result`. Ya verifiqué que los datos de conexión sean los correctos, y a pesar de diferentes `querys` me sigue marcando lo mismo.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "inventarios");
if($mysqli === false) {
    die("ERROR: No se estableció la conexión. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if(!isset ($_REQUEST['buscar']))
    exit;

$sql    = "select 'Nom_Art' from 'articulos' WHERE 'Nom_Art' LIKE '%$buscar%'";
$result = $conex->listaObjetos($sql);

if(count($result) < 0)
    exit;

$data = array();
foreach($result as $r) {
    $data[] = array(
        'label' => $r->buscar,
        'value' => $r->buscar
    );
}

echo json_encode($data);
flush();
?>
```

Y ese código es utilizado aquí.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<title>prueba</title>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-Validation-Engine/2.6.4/validationEngine.jquery.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-Validation-Engine/2.6.4/jquery.validationEngine.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-Validation-Engine/2.6.4/languages/jquery.validationEngine-es.js"></script>
<style>
    .top-buffer { 
        margin-top:20px; 
    }
</style>
</head>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   $("#buscar").autocomplete({source:"llenado.php", minLength:'4'});
  });
</script>


 <body>

 <form>
<p><label for="buscar">Priueba</label>
   <input type="text" name="buscar" id="buscar"  method="get" size="35" minlength="4"/>
</p>
</form>
```

Comment: Porque no comienzas a debugear con los datos que te entrega `->listaObjetos($sql);` imprimele un `var_dump($result)` espero que te genere datos... postea imagen para ver qué te entrega

Comment: Yo intenté con este link, está muy simple https://www.codexworld.com/autocomplete-textbox-using-jquery-php-mysql/comment-page-1/#comment-49918

Answer (score 1):

Intentalo de este modo.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "inventarios");
if ($mysqli === false){
die("ERROR: No se estableció la conexión. ". mysqli_connect_error());
}
if (!isset($_REQUEST['buscar'])) exit;
$sql = "SELECT Nom_Art FROM articulos WHERE Nom_Art LIKE'%".$buscar."%'";
$result = $conex->listaObjetos($sql);
if (count($result) < 0) exit;
$data = array();
foreach ($result as $r) {
$data[] = array (
'label' => $r[0]->buscar, 
'value' => $r[1]->buscar);
}
echo json_encode($data);
flush();
?>
```

Comment: Jajajajaja no me imprimia el código xD

Comment: Realicé cambios que me sugeriste ero aún así sigue marcando el mensaje de no search resultados. Cambie el query por select *from artículos y un así me mstr como si no hubiese encontrado dta

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estas invocando una variable no declarada en tu consulta.

```
if(!isset ($_REQUEST['buscar']))
    exit;

$sql    = "select 'Nom_Art' from 'articulos' WHERE 'Nom_Art' LIKE '%$buscar%'";
```

La variable *$buscar* no tiene datos. Necesitas asignarle el valor de *$_REQUEST['buscar']*

Y otra, por seguridad necesitas validar los datos que vas a pasar a una consulta, para evitar inyecciones sql.

```
if(!isset ($_REQUEST['buscar']))
    exit;
$buscar  = $_REQUEST['buscar'];
$buscar = mysqli_real_escape_string($buscar);
$sql    = "select 'Nom_Art' from 'articulos' WHERE 'Nom_Art' LIKE '%$buscar%'";
```